# Problems with PASSWORD_ARGON2I in PHP 7.3.6

Tags: php, argon

I read that there is a problem with PHP 7.2 and if you want to use ARGON2 you need to compile php using –with-password-argon2

In my case I'm using PHP 7.3.6

php -v

> PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2019 11:43:32) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.3.6, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.3.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans

If I try:

```
var_dump(password_hash('password', PASSWORD_ARGON2I));
```

it returns:

> PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2I - assumed 'PASSWORD_ARGON2I' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

More info: MacOS Sierra

Comment: Okay, did you compile 7.3 with Argon support? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: ./configure —with-password-argon2
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: —with-password-argon2
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `—with-password-argon2': machine `—with-password' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub —with-password-argon2 failed

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--` not `—`?